# Missing application on running apps menu on android tablet

Tags: android, menu, tablet

Context: I'm creating an android application (with the help of roboguice, android annotations and others). It contains multiple fragments and activities and so far works good.

When testing on a 3.0 or 4.0 tablet (the target devices) everything runs fine except that the app isnt showing in the running apps menu (third bottom from left to right in the bottom bar). Not when started, or running in background (hidden/paused).

I haven't found any relative information as to why this might be happening so i don't know if im missing something on the project configuration, or the code, or the manifest.

Comment: It's not the usual way. You might had modify your manifest in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that button shows only the recent apps and only when you are not on the app itself, However i also had to add the line

```
android:excludeFromRecents="false"
```

to my android manifest on the main (launcher) activity, so it shows on the recents menu when im outside the application.